# Can GRUB load Windows directly?

Tags: windows, dual-boot, grub, boot-loader

I have a question about how dual booting works with GRUB bootloader and Windows bootloader. Once the GRUB bootloader is loaded and when we choose Windows, does it directly load Windows or hand over the control to the Windows bootloader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It hands over the control to the Windows bootloader.

If your system uses a legacy BIOS version of GRUB, booting Windows is done in the GRUB configuration file by first a `set root` command or an equivalent `search` command to select the partition that contains the Windows bootloader, and then `chainloader +1` to invoke the [PBR (partition boot record)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_boot_record) of that partition. In other words, doing essentially the same thing a standard BIOS MBR code would do since the first hard disks in the days of MS-DOS.

On the other hand, if you're booting UEFI-style, the UEFI version of GRUB will boot Windows by selecting the EFI System Partition, and then doing a `chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` to start the UEFI Windows bootloader. If Windows was the only OS in the system, the `bootmgfw.efi` would be directly registered in the UEFI NVRAM boot variables and would be directly loaded by the UEFI firmware. In Linux, you can use `efibootmgr -v` to view the UEFI NVRAM boot variables - but only if the system is booted UEFI-style. In Windows, you can open a Command Prompt as an Administrator, and then run `bcdedit /enum FIRMWARE` for the same thing.

(When dual-booting with UEFI-style boot, it might be important to keep the Windows bootloader registered in the UEFI NVRAM boot variables, just not necessary as the first item in the boot order. If you delete the NVRAM entry for Windows altogether, Windows might re-insert its bootloader at the top boot priority as an attempt to self-heal.)